# Is it possible to trim the colour when using Bootstrap Color

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

When i am pasting a valid colour code with spaces , it says invalid colour code .

For example in case we paste  #00FFFF   under the text input , it says invalid color code

Can we modify this ?

```
 $('#colorPicker').colorpicker().on('showPicker changeColor', function(e) {
    $('#colorPickerForm').bootstrapValidator('revalidateField', 'color');
  });

  // When reset is clicked 
  $("#resetcolor").click(function(e) {
    $('#color').val("#444444");
    $('#colorPicker').colorpicker('setValue', '#444444');
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vpu25k1g/54/

Comment: *"When i am pasting a valid colour code with spaces , it says invalid colour code."* ***With*** spaces? That's because if it has spaces, it's not a valid color code.

Comment: ya agree , so can we trim that ??

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value entered trim the white spaces instantly .
Or you can wait for certain number of character and then apply your trim

Just check how the jquery [replace](http://api.jquery.com/?s=.replace) function work.And the jquery event.

> jQuery.Event {type: "changeColor", color: b, value: "#444444e", …}

```
function(e) {
        console.log(e);
        let color = e.value.replace(/\s/g,'');
        $('#color').val(color);
        $('#colorPickerForm').bootstrapValidator('revalidateField', 'color');
      });
```